# I added ajax to my voting buttons and it is working but it is not updating number of votes without refreshing

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I use Django and I built my voting system and added ajax to it to avoid refreshing my page after clicking "UP" or "DOWN". And it is working (it updates my buttons without actually refreshing page). But my votes numbers are also included in the same part of code but they are not updating alongside buttons. To view change in number of votes I actually need to refresh whole site (f5).

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

My voting section:

```
Vote Up: {{ total_voteup }} Vote Down: {{ total_votedown }}
{% if is_voteup %}
    <form method='POST' action="{% url 'voteup' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type='submit' id="voteup" name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}">Revert /\</button>
    </form>
{% elif is_votedown %}
    <form method='POST' action="{% url 'votedown' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type='submit' id="votedown" name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}">Revert \/</button>
    </form>
{% else %}
    <form method='POST' action="{% url 'voteup' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type='submit' id="voteup" name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}">/\</button>
    </form>
    <form method='POST' action="{% url 'votedown' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type='submit' id="votedown" name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}">\/</button>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

My js scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(event){
        $(document).on('click', '#voteup', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var pk = $(this).attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{% url "voteup" %}',
                data: {'question_id': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    $('#voting_section').html(response['form'])
                    console.log($('#voting_section').html(response['form']));
                },

                error: function(rs, e){
                    console.log(rs.responseText);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(event){
        $(document).on('click', '#votedown', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var pk = $(this).attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{% url "votedown" %}',
                data: {'question_id': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    $('#voting_section').html(response['form'])
                    console.log($('#voting_section').html(response['form']));
                },
                error: function(rs, e){
                    console.log(rs.responseText);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't know much about js or ajax.

### Edit

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # Authorization
    path('signup/', views.signupuser, name='signupuser'),
    path('login/', views.loginuser, name='loginuser'),
    path('logout/', views.logoutuser, name='logoutuser'),

    # User Page
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('askaquestion/', views.askaquestion, name='askaquestion'),
    path('viewquestion/<int:question_pk>', views.viewquestion, name='viewquestion'),
    path('viewquestion/<int:question_pk>/answered', views.questionanswered, name='questionanswered'),
    path('viewquestion/<int:question_pk>/delete', views.deletequestion, name='deletequestion'),
    path('viewanswer/<int:answer_pk>', views.viewanswer, name='viewanswer'),
    path('appreciatedanswer/<int:answer_pk>', views.appreciatedanswer, name='appreciatedanswer'),
    path('viewanswer/<int:answer_pk>/delete', views.deleteanswer, name='deleteanswer'),
    path('voteup/', views.voteup, name='voteup'),
    path('votedown/', views.votedown, name='votedown'),
    path('questiondetails/<int:question_pk>', views.questiondetails, name='questiondetails'),

    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Comment: Can you post your urls..py?  Also, I would  not use .on for something like voting, because the user will click multiple times and ajax will be called many times. Instead use .one()

Comment: I changed .on to .one. Thank you. And I also added my urls.py

Answer (score 0):

ajax allows you to specify an element as the target for your response. Instead of relaying on a success function, you could have ajax put the response directly in the total_voteup/down element. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url "votedown" %}',
    data: {'question_id': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
    dataType: 'json',
    target: 'total_voteup'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to change it but when I replace my success/error part to "target: 'total_voteup'" then it is not working. I also tried to put target: 'voting_section' since this is what is updating but it is also not working. Can you please tell me what am I missing ?

Comment: I believe target goes by id so you'll need to make sure the element you want to put the response in has an id

Comment: I tried typing in various id, I even tried to add hash "#" before just in case, but I am afraid that it is not working :/ 

Maybe you have some other idea how can I do this or what am I doing wrong ? Thanks